# Need to retain quality of image when rotating that image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-rotation, image-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to retain original quality of image while rotating in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814544/need-to-retain-original-quality-of-image-while-rotating-in-iphone-sdk)

In my app, I can rotate an image by 90 degrees. When I rotate a number of times... it is getting blurred (pixel clarity is missing). I lost the img quality. Can anyone suggest way to implement this.

Here I used a button to rotate the image. The code used for Rotation is:

```
- (UIImage *)rotateImage:(UIImage *) img
{

     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


     if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) 
     {
          CGContextRotateCTM (context, M_PI_2);
     } 

     else if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) 
     {
          CGContextRotateCTM (context, -(M_PI_2));
     }

     else if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) 
     {
          // NOTHING
     } 

     else if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) 
     {
         CGContextRotateCTM (context, M_PI_2);
     }

     //CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);

     CGContextTranslateCTM(context,0, -(img.size.width));
     [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.height,img.size.width)];


     UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     appDelegate.savedImage=newImage;

     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     CGContextRelease(context);
     return newImage;
     }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If rotation is the only manipulation that you do, then I would always keep the original and go from there for each future rotation. e.g. Instead of rotating by +7 and +3 and -2 one after the other I would then get back to the original and rotate by +8 only once. For the next rotation I would scrap the rotated image and get back to the original again.

Comment: you have already asked for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814544/need-to-retain-original-quality-of-image-while-rotating-in-iphone-sdk   ; if you need to add new code or text just edit your old question, instead of create a new question...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a copy of the original image changing the orientation like this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [img CGImage];
UIImage *rotatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

you has to put the second line in every of your conditions and change the orientation parameter to the correct value for each case, check the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage%3ascale%3aorientation%3a) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Rotating at the view level will preserve the bitmap fidelity (namely, it doesn't touch it).

ie:

```
#define DEG2RAD(d) (M_PI * d / 180.0)
...
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEG2RAD(45));
```

Unfortunately you then need to look at anti-aliasing the rotated image with a inner border. That's already been answered here before.

Hope this helps!